# EntityFramework,Add a property and divide by other columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this database model where I have one column holding a score, which in this case is a summuraized value of all the score give to an item over the past x months..anyway..
and I also have another column which holds the number of votes that has been done dureing the same x months as the score...
(the score can be give by a user in the values of 1-10)

I now need to get the score/votes value.. and I would like to create a new property for my entity-model that holds the value of score/votes.. how would I do this?.. I have tried by simply creating a Scalar Property, but I just cant get it to work.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did my answer help? if so would you mind marking it as correct. If you need any more help please let me know

Answer (score 3):

You could use a partial class:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
     public double MyComputedValue
     {
        get
        {
            return this.Score/this.Value;
        }
     }
}
```

This allows you to add functionality to an Entity - the partial class name should match your entity name (which is also declared as a partial class) when you use it you will see that both partial class properties are available in the logical class. This could be compared (in a fashion) to a Join on two tables in a database that create one logical structure.